# Optimal way to handle "return"?

Tags: php, class

I need an advice how to handle function with lots of different return's better. 
I have this simple log in function in my class:

```
public function login($email, $password){

$record = // Go to database and find what we need.

if($record){
   // Check pass, $user_match = TRUE;
} else {
   return 1;         //No such user. Please register!
}

$active = (1 == $record['is_active']) ? TRUE : FALSE;
$verified = (1 == $record['is_verified']) ? TRUE : FALSE;

//User email and password matched:
if($user_match == true){
   if($verified === true){
       // Start session and insert to db table "online_users"
   // Check that user was inserted to table: $confirm = $stmt->rowCount();

         if($confirm !== 1){
           return 2; //Unexpected technical error. Please try again in a moment.
         }

       return 0;     //0 means that all clear, we good to go.

       } else {
           return 3; //not verified
       }
    } else {
        return 4;    // no match with email and pass, reject!
    }
}
```

The problem is, that now all the time I need to check all return's, something like that:

```
$log = $user->login($_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);
if($log === 0) {
    //Log in & edirect
} elseif ($log === 1) {
    //No such user. Tell to register
} elseif($log === 2){
    //technical error, try again
} elseif($log === 3){
    //Not verified
} elseif($log === 4){
    //wrong password
```

It's really annoying right now, and imagine if I would need to check like 20 return's? Is there any better way? How to do it more efficient and faster?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because not all are exceptional situations. Don't use exceptions for flow control

Comment: Of course they are exceptions. If someone is trying to login, the expected situation is that that will work. If it doesn't, that's an exception.

Comment: No. It is expected that users mistype their password, so if the user is rejected (wrong password) it is NOT exceptional. This is a normal day to day situation that should be handled in the code, not by exceptions

Comment: (so yes, "return 2" is an exception, but the others arent)

Comment: I think you are right @Nanne. As I understand myself, I can only put "try" block around my return 2.

Comment: Bonus: `$active = (bool)$record['is_active'];` Your boolean logic is... overly complex, to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rethink the *purpose* of this function and structure the return types accordingly. If the purpose is to log the user in, there can only be one answer: it either worked or it didn't. So the primary return type of the function should be a boolean. How to differentiate between different causes for failure is a different topic.

Option 1: throw exceptions:

```
try {
    if (!$foo->login()) {
        echo 'Invalid credentials';
    }
} catch (UserNotActiveException $e) {
    ...
} catch (UserNotValidatedException $e) {
    ...
}
```

Not necessarily the most elegant option, since a failed login isn't really an *exceptional* circumstance.

Option 2: save the error state in the login provider:

```
if (!$foo->login()) {
    echo "You're not logged in because ", $foo->loginError();
}
```

Whether this is good or not depends on how the class is used otherwise, you may not want to make it too stateful.

Option 3: separate the problem of login from *what is the user's state* entirely:

```
if (!$foo->login($user)) {
    switch ($foo->currentStatus($user)) {
        case $foo::ALL_OK :
             echo 'Login credentials invalid';
             break;
        case $foo::ACCOUNT_INACTIVE :
             ...
    }
}
```

Option 4: return a status object:

```
$result = $foo->login();
switch ($result->status) {
    case $result::ALL_OK :
        ...
}
```

That's essentially what you're doing now, just without the magic numbers.

Comment: +1 - this is where I was going with my answer, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) would be one way to provide clear handling of error code, depending on how this fits into the rest of your application.

As was pointed out by Nanne, you shouldn't use exceptions for flow control: they should only indicate exceptional circumstances.  The technical error is clearly an exceptional circumstance and using exceptions for this would be clear and appropriate.

Using exceptions for the rest of it is less clear, but still an option.  You could simply throw an exception with different error messages for each failure condition, or different exception classes that have appropriate handlers for the failure conditions.

This *is* starting to break the semantics of exceptions, depending on how this code fits in with the rest.  Being able to call the login function elsewhere without having to worry about it throwing inappropriate exceptions might be useful or necessary, for example.

In the end, there's probably no getting around the need to have explicit checks for each of those failing conditions and returning them inside the function.  Again, depending on how flexible this needs to be, you could just return true on a successful login, or an error message on failure (using `===` to verify that the result is true, not just truthy).  Or you could return an object with a success property and an error condition, which at least makes your error handling code a matter of checking the success and handling the error code.

If you need significantly different error handling mechanisms for each failure condition, then returning a [constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) for each failure case could at least make it clear what's going on in the code.  You can then return `LOGIN_PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH` instead of a cryptic number, which could then be checked in your error code.

Comment: It would not really help the situation as now you need to check the exception, so you're in the same boat. Also, you should not use exceptions for flow control => "return 2" is an exception, the rest are NOT exceptional situations and should not throw exceptions

Comment: @Nanne Fair enough, exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control.  I suspect that this could be rewritten to take advantage of exceptions though.  I'll expand my answer to clarify this a bit.

Comment: But a wrong password or a non-verified user shouldn't raise an exception, it's just a return value that should be handled.

Comment: Seems I was beaten to most of the alternatives, but I expanded my answer a bit to help clarify where exceptions should be used and some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `switch` statement if you need many `if-else` statements:

```
$log = $user->login($_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);

switch ($log) {
   case 1:
     break; 
   case 2:
     break;
   //etc....
}
```

To clarify error codes use named constants or static array of name=>code pairs instead of "magic numbers"

```
static $ERROR_CODES = array(
   "WRONG_PASSWORD"=>1,
   "WRONG_EMAIL"=>2
);

switch ($log) {
   case LoginClass::$ERROR_CODES["WRONG_PASSWORD"]:
     break; 
   case LoginClass::$ERROR_CODES["WRONG_EMAIL"]:
     break;
   //etc....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use INI Files

write your bugs in an ini file:

```
1 = "Error"
2 = " Technical"
3 = "Network"
...
```

And save it into and ini file. Then use this code:

```
<?php
$array = parse_ini("er.ini");
echo $array[$log];
?>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood OP.

Comment: Sure. You can write it in Assembly as well. Not really an answer, though.